# PArent category with count

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue related to query, i have a table for categories, Sub categories are also mentioned the same table with its parent id..

The problem is that i need to get count of parent catgeories that how much catgeories are being added inside that parent category... How can i modify the below query that it will give me count againt the parent category name...

Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
P.catName,
P.cID,
P.catParent,
P.catLink,
P.catIcon,
P.catStatus, 
U.catName AS Parent_name 
FROM `dev_web_categories` AS P 
LEFT JOIN `dev_web_categories` AS U ON U.cID = P.catParent
```

Table is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as:

```
SELECT
category.catName AS CategoryName,
(select count(*) from dev_web_categories as subCategory where subCategory.catParent = category.cID) AS TotalSubCategories
FROM dev_web_categories AS category
WHERE category.catParent = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create function in mysql 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@localhost FUNCTION `GetAllNode`(GivenID INT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children TEXT;
    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;
    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;
    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;
        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(cID AS CHAR(50))) AS qc
        FROM dev_web_categories WHERE `catParent` = front_id) A ;
        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END
```

// And call function using cID

SELECT cID ,GetAllNode(cID) FROM dev_web_categories